# Locally finite collection of support

Tags: differential-geometry

I want to prove the following statement. Let $\{ \rho_\alpha \}$ be a collection of function on a manifold M and $\omega$ a smooth k-form with compact support on M. If the collection $\{ supp \rho_\alpha \}$ is locally finite, then $\rho_\alpha \omega=0$ for all but finitely many $\alpha$. How I have to do to prove this?

Answer (score 3):

The confusion perhaps lies at the phrase: "for all but finitely many $\alpha$". To this end, let us clarify the following:

Let $X$ be a set. Let $P(x)$ be a proposition on $X$. To say for all $x$ except finitely many satisfy $P(x)$, we **mean** that $\{$ $x\in X$ $:$ $P(x)$ is false $\}$ is finite.

Okay, to proceed with your problem, let us first prove something that will turn out to be of help.

**Proposition:**
Let $M$ be a differentiable manifold and $\omega: M\rightarrow \bigcup_{p\in M}A_k(T_pM)$ be a $k-form$. Let $\rho: M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  be a function.

Then, $supp \rho\omega \subseteq supp\rho \cap supp \omega$.

Proof:
Let $p\in M$ such that $(\rho\omega)_p\neq 0$ . Hence, $\rho(p)\omega_p\neq 0$. We may assume $\rho(p)\neq 0$; in which case, $\omega_p=0$. By the standard properties of the closure of a set, the result follows.

Now, let us prove your problem:
We aim to show that $\{$ $\alpha\in A $ $:$ $p_{\alpha}\omega \neq 0$ $\}$ is finite. As $supp\omega$ is compact, there exists a neighborhood $W$ of $supp\omega$ such that $W$ intersects only finitely many $supp\rho_{\alpha}$. As $supp\omega \subseteq W$, $supp\omega$ intersects only finitely many $supp\rho_{\alpha}$. This means that $\{$ $\alpha\in A$ $:$ $supp\omega$ intersects $supp\rho_{\alpha}$ $\}$ is finite. In other words, for all but finitely many $\alpha$, $supp\omega \cap supp\rho_{\alpha}$ is empty. By our proposition above, this means that for all but finitely many $\alpha$, $supp\rho_{\alpha}\omega$ is empty. This is the conclusion we seek. $\square$

Comment: Did you use $A$ to denote the index set of $\alpha$? And, $\rho_\alpha\omega\neq 0$ means that $\rho_\alpha\omega$ is not identically zero? Thank you.

Comment: How did your $W$ come about? I fail to find such $W$ by employing compactness of $\mathsf{supp}(\omega)$. Thank you.

Comment: @Steve By local finiteness, for each $p\in supp\omega$  there exists a neighborhood $W_p$ for which $W_p$ intersects $supp\rho_{\alpha}$ for finitely many $\alpha$. Let $W=\bigcup_{p\in supp\omega}W_p$. Clearly, $supp\omega \subseteq W$.

Comment: Didn't you extract any finite subcover $\{W_{p_i}\}$ from the open cover $\{W_p\}$ and then set $W=\bigcup_i W_{p_i}$? That way, $W$ would be sure to intersect finitely many $\mathsf{supp}(\rho_\alpha)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\in M$.  Since the supports are locally finite, there is a neighbhorhood $U$ of $M$ that meets only a finite number of the supports, say $\mathrm{supp}_{\alpha_1}, \cdots \mathrm{supp}_{\alpha_n}.$  Then if $\alpha$ is chosen that is not in $\{\alpha_1, \cdots \alpha_n\}$, $\rho_{\alpha} = 0$ on $U$.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have a doubt yet. I have a neighborhood like that for all $x \in M$. And maybe in all of this neighborhood different support are non zero...Then in M how i could conclude that $\rho_\alpha \omega$ is zero only for many finitely $\alpha$?

Comment: Remember, continuous functions are zero off their support.

Comment: Ok. Sorry if I'm so tedius but I don't understand well. It's clear that in every point the relation hold. But in different point different function are non zero...how I can conclude in all M? we don't use yet the hyp. that $\omega$ is compact support...

Comment: this property holds at every point of $M$.  Every point has a neighborhood for which all but finitely many of these functions are zero.

Comment: @ncmathsadist Excuse me. I'm wondering if $\rho_\alpha=0$ on the complement of $U$. Thank you.